# JQuery Droppable Highlight on Hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to create an effect where i basically highlight all fields (td) below the draggable div. I know intersect: "touch" does the trick visually, however this leaves me with some problems:

1. The draggable should only be able to hover and touch multiple cells at a time - but only within one row!
2. I want to fire events depending on the stop position. Without using intersect i have one specific td i drop on. Now i have up to 4. But i only want the first one for future event handling. So basically the outer left td it touches as the start position!

Any way to adjust my code to solve these problems? I couldn't find anything. Thank you so much!!

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="droppable"></td>
      <td class="droppable"></td>
      <td class="droppable"></td>
      <td class="droppable"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="droppable"></td>
      <td class="droppable"></td>
      <td class="droppable"></td>
      <td class="droppable"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="draggable">
  <span>Draggable</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.draggable {
  background-color: green;
  width: 75px;
}

.bg-change {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
$('.droppable').droppable({
    hoverClass: "bg-change",
  tolerance: "touch"
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ohfztugh/13/

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways to do it.

> **1. First Trick:**

You can make use of `over` and `out` method to achieve this.

Something like this

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
    //hoverClass: "bg-change",
  tolerance: "touch",

  over: function(){

  $(this).parent("tr").siblings().removeClass("bg-change");
  $(this).parent("tr").addClass("bg-change");

  },

  out:function(){


  $(this).parent("tr").removeClass("bg-change");

  } ,

drop:function(){


  $(".droppable").parent("tr").removeClass("bg-change");
  $(this).parent("tr").addClass("bg-change");

  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ohfztugh/16/)

Not perfect . but it will surely give you an idea to proceed.

> **2. Second way of doing it**

Simply make your tr droppable . and use `torelance:"fit"`

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
$('tr').droppable({
    hoverClass: "bg-change",
  tolerance: "fit",


});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ohfztugh/17/)

or make `tolerance:"intersect"`

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
$('tr').droppable({
    hoverClass: "bg-change",
  tolerance: "intersect",


});
```

[**Working Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/ohfztugh/19/)

If you want single cell droppable then do this

```
$('td,th').droppable({
    hoverClass: "bg-change",
  tolerance: "intersect",


});
```

[**Working Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/ohfztugh/20/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not exactly what i meant. I want to achieve a similar effect to here: http://fullcalendar.io/ where i can hover an event over multiple cells and chaqnge their background and then have the most left cell as my "droppable target"

Comment: This only highlights the cell my cursor is over for me.

Comment: that is what you example shows .. right ?  else can you please elaborate

Comment: Basically if you visit the link to fullcalendar. An event (3 days long) will highlight all the days its over when dragged. In this case 3 days, obviously. If i use tolerance: touch i get the same visual effect. However then i can't fire any events on "stop" as i now effectively hover over multiple droppables. But i want only one field to accept the draggable but still highlight all the fields im hovering over

Comment: you need to code in drop method .. like this .. only only field accpets it and just registers checkout   https://jsfiddle.net/ohfztugh/22/  and   https://jsfiddle.net/ohfztugh/21/

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant add this fiddle as comment I posted it as answer.

```
$('.event').draggable({
  opacity: .7,
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: 'invalid',

});
$('td').droppable({
    hoverClass: "hover",
    tolerance: "touch",

  drop: function (event, ui) {
    if (false === dropped) {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
      dropped = true;
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo($(this));
    }
  },
  activate: function (event, ui) {
    dropped = false;
  }
});
```

activate: prevents touch from firing multiple times.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wce2x8tf/12/)

Hope this helps you in the right direction!

Sorry for my bad english!

(my problem is that it always snaps left instead of most touched td)